# Showing an wrong element while finding max element in the array

Tags: java, arrays, max

Code:

```
public class FindMax {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {1,10,2,6,7,9,8,5,8,3,1,3,10,5,8,3,9,3,8,2,3,3,10,5,8,8,4,7,2,3,4,3,10,8,7,9,1,3,4,2,6,6,9,6,2,10,10,4,6,3,4,1,1,3,8,4,10,3,9,5,3,10,4,7,10,7,1,7};
        int max = maximizeSum(nums);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
    public static int maximizeSum(int[] nums) {
        int max = nums[0];
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length - 1; i++){
            max = Math.max(nums[i],nums[i+1]);
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

**In this code, it is showing an output 7 instead of showing output 10.**

I tried some other conditions, some are working correctly some are showing wrong output. Can anyone tell me why the incorrect output is showing for certain cases.

Comment: You are basically only comparing the last two elements. You should only overwrite the `max` variable if an element is indeed greater than the current maximum.

Comment: I wonder the reason for "Sum" in the name of the `maximizeSum()` method

Answer (score 0):

You're currently looking for the max element between each value and it's next, so at the end you just get the max between the last value and the previous one

To find the max, get the max between the current value and the max you've got so far. You can initialize your `max` to the first value and start iterate at the second (`i=1`) value

```
public static int maximizeSum(int[] nums) {
    int max = nums[0];
    for(int i=1; i<nums.length ; i++){
        max = Math.max(nums[i], max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is incorrect.

You are simply evaluating the maximum of every two elements.
The last two are *1* and *7*, thus *max* is assigned *7*.

Check *max* before assigning the value.

```java
public static int maximizeSum(int[] nums) {
    int max = nums[0], value;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length - 1; i++){
        value = Math.max(nums[i],nums[i+1]);
        if (value > max) max = value;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Another way to do this is one item at a time, as opposed to every two.

```java
int max = nums[0];
for (int value : nums) {
    if (value > max) max = value;
}
return max;
```

Additionally, you can use the *Collections#max* method, although you'd need to use an *Integer* array, and not an *int* array.

```java
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(nums));
```

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating the method, the maximum value is determined by comparing each pair of adjacent values, without comparing the maximum value to those values. For example, in your code implementation, the method compares the first two numbers, where 10 is greater than 1, thus establishing 10 as the maximum value. Subsequently, it compares 10 and 2, which also yields the correct result. However, an issue arises when comparing 2 and 6, as it only compares 6 to 2, overlooking the previous maximum value of 10. Consequently, the logic flaw lies in consistently comparing adjacent numbers without considering the maximum value. To address this, the solution entails identifying the maximum value and subsequently comparing it to the remaining numbers, rather than solely comparing adjacent pairs.

Alternatively, you can utilize built-in functions in Java to find the maximum value within a list. This approach eliminates the need for manual comparison and ensures a more efficient and reliable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please use the formatting tools to make your answer more clear. Maybe even use some code examples. Your answer is hard to read in this state.